# Adicionar valores em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Em python, quando imprimo certa variável (após um laço) tenho como resultado:

[3]

[7]

[13]

[4]

> os valores estão dentro de uma variável a . Daí quando faço lista.append(a) e imprimo, tenho:
>   [3]

[3,7]

[3,7,13]

[3,7,13,4]

> E o que eu preciso é de uma lista do tipo:

lista= [3,7,13,4]

> como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o método append do Array você adiciona elementos no fim da sua lista.

```
lista = [];

lista.append(3);

lista.append(7);

lista.append(13);

lista.append(4);

print(lista);
```

Comment: não funciona assim pq na hora de imprimir sai errado

Comment: Como está o código atual? Atualize a pergunta sobre o que um código parecido com o que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando o comentário do @ViniciusFarias, caso você queira adicionar vários itens de uma lista em outra lista por vez, você pode utilizar o método `.extend()`. Seu uso seria algo do tipo:

```py
lista = [3, 7, 13, 4]
lista2 = [5, 8]
lista.extend(lista2)

print(lista)
# [3, 7, 13, 4, 5, 8]
```

Para saber todos os métodos, acesse a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).